# How to intercept an authentication request in ASP.net webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms, authentication

I have user's who are losing their data because they sit on a page too long, then are asked to log back in.  I want to do the following:

1) Instead of redirecting them to a login page, I want to cancel the current request and give the user a popup dialog box to login with.

2) When the login is successful, I want the user to be sent back to their form, with all data intact.  (Even better if the request could go through without sending them back to that form, but this is optional).

How can I intercept these authentication requests, and present the user with a popup login?

I am using ASP.net forms authentication.

Comment: What do you mean in 1) by "cancel the request"? Once the request is server side, you can't really cancel it.

Comment: Your right, cancel isn't the right word.  I just don't want the form data to be flushed.

Answer (score 2):

You can intercept this event on Application_AuthenticateRequest in Global.asax

But, you need be more specific, are you using the ASP.NET Forms Authentication?

Added:

Try this and reply me

In Global.asax

```
void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (HttpContext.Current.User == null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new
                        FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "Anonymous", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, "Anonymous");

        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

        HttpCookie cookie =
           new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        FormsIdentity id = new FormsIdentity(ticket);

        System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal principal = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(id, ticket.UserData.Split(new char[] { '|' }));

        Context.User = principal;
    }

}
```

In a web form

```
string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;

    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

    if (authTicket.UserData == "Anonymous")
    {

        //Throw the login popup

    }
    else
    {

        //Some Code

    }
```

Comment: Yes, I am.  Sorry, I added that.  Can you elaborate on how to intercept within that event?  I do have some unhandled exception handling in global.asax, so I've used it a bit, but not that event.

Comment: I suppose that you have something like that, in your web.config: <authentication mode="Forms"><forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx"></forms></authentication>, right?

Comment: I have an authentication section, but its blank with defaults.

Comment: What does this .asax code do?  Does it set an auth ticket to "Anonymous" then update the cookie likewise?  I've not done authentication tickets manually before.

Comment: Yes, this code adds (manually) a "ticket" as Anonymous, the problem is: the users will be authenticated (always) as Anonymous, then you need validate in each webform if the user is authenticated as Anonymous or not. This solution is very complex, I don't think this is the correct, but at least I give you an new idea to take in mind. Sorry for my english : )... keep me informed of your advances please

Comment: This solution is messy, but I did learn more about manual authentication tickets.  Do you know of a good guide to the objects available in Applicaton_AuthenticateRequest?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a master page?  You could redirect to there when login is required, not a separate login page.  In the login code in the master page you then decided whether to redirect to a proper, standalone login page, or make a login div visible as a popup.

Comment: I am using 2 levels of nested masterpages, but this doesn't address the data that was in the webform before the authentication request (which is the important part).  A popup div could work for the logging back in part, though.

Comment: Can you elaborate on making a login div popup?